# How to display different indicators such as MA and RSI in one pine script code

Tags: pine-script

Is it Possible to display different indicators such as MA and RSI in and out of price chart simultaneously in one code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Overlay and sub-window indicators can't be combined into one indicator as of the moment.